# Django Tastypie pasrsing multi part form data

Tags: python, django, tastypie

My app is receiving multipart form data as part of the request. It's in the request.body as a String. Is there a easy way to parse it and convert it to a python dictionary

My request.body gives me the following

```
'------WebKitFormBoundaryUljHZoRAHNz2UgwB\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="password"\r\n\r\n123\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryUljHZoRAHNz2UgwB\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="email"\r\n\r\na@b.com\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryUljHZoRAHNz2UgwB--\r\n'
```

I am converting it to a dict by

```
        x= re.findall('name=.*\s\s.*\s.*',request.body)
        z={}
        for a in x:
            z[repr(re.findall('".+"',a))[3:-3]]=re.findall('\s\S+\s',a)[0][1:-1]
        requestData=z
```

But it's very inefficient and buggy. i.e if the value is empty it throws an error

Answer (score 1):

Use Django's MultiPartParser: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/multipartparser.py#L45

```
from django.http.multipartparser import MultiPartParser

parser = MultiPartParser(request.META, request.body, request.upload_handlers)
POST, FILES = parser.parse()
```

Or try:

```
request._load_post_and_files()
request.POST
request.FILES
```

Comment: A typo on your answer it should be `parser = MultiPartParser(request.META, request.body,request.upload_handlers) ` But I get this error `raise MultiPartParserError('Invalid Content-Type: %s' % content_type)`

Comment: What was the content-type?

Comment: content_type="application/json"

Comment: Should be content_type="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @SeánHayes I have similar issues. Can you please answer this?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68002738/having-issue-in-handling-multipart-form-data-in-django-rest-framework